# I have a Scala List, how can I get a TraversableOnce?

Tags: scala

Starting with a Scala list.

```
val list = List(1,2,3,4)
```

How can I convert it to a TraversableOnce?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You already have one, since `List[A]` is a subtype of `TraversableOnce[A]`. You should not need to do anything to convert it.

To verify this:

```
scala> implicitly[List[Int] <:< TraversableOnce[Int]]
res0: <:<[List[Int],TraversableOnce[Int]] = <function1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list.iterator
```

would do the trick if you specifically need to iterate, but your list is already a `TraversableOnce`

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List